# Reverse of Modulo Operator

Tags: arithmetic

I have posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348364/what-is-the-reverse-of-the-modulo-operator) originally in Stack Overflow.

The question is, ***"Is there a mathematical approach in getting the reverse of the Modulo Operator with given result $r$ and divisor $d$?"***

So, the Modulo Operator `%` gives the remainder when dividing two numbers:

`3 % 2 = 1`

I will be asking the same question here.

> Is there a mathematical approach in getting the reverse of the Modulo Operator with given result $r$ and divisor $d$?

**NOTES:**
As I have stressed in the SO question, the answers should be limited to numbers which can be converted to a valid time in the format `HHMMss.xxx` where HH is the 24-hour respresention of hours, M is the minutes, s as seconds and x as millisecond. You need not worry about that part though because I can do a checking using Regex for that. You can check my updated [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348364/what-is-the-reverse-of-the-modulo-operator).

Comment: if you write the definitions then the answer would be trivial.

Comment: Since $3\mathbin{\%}2=1$ as well as $5\mathbin{\%}2=1$, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @egreg : that only shows that the reverse operation is not a function, the question does make sense.

Comment: Just write all numbers of the form $dk+r$ starting from $k=0$ until you're tired. What's the meaning of this?

Comment: @egreg : that is similar to values for arcos , arcsin etc.

Comment: So in the integers the answer is the particular coset of the ideal generated by $d$.  Pick your notation.  $r+(d)$ or $r+d{Z}$.

Comment: If you want the *least* $m$ such that $m \equiv r \pmod d$, then just set $m = r$. e.g., `1 % 2 = 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments and in the original Stack Overflow post, there are infinitely many numbers which divided by $\mathbf{d}$ have remainder $\mathbf{r}$. So there is a reverse operator given $d$ and $r$, but it will give you infinitely many solutions of the form $d\cdot k +r$.

Comment: I would like to point out that the answers, as I know that there could be multiple answers, should be less than 240000000. that will limit the "infinite" answers, right? Moreover, I would like to convert the numbers to a time format, so, [00 - 23][00-59][00-59]. But of course, you need not think about the time formatting. I can do that using code.

Comment: @Geoman I guess you cold write a $while$ loop and make one of the conditions be $d\cdot k + r < 240000000$ while you keep increasing $k$.

Comment: And yes, then there would be a finite number of answers

Comment: nice suggestion @F.A. I think that will be faster. Thanks!